# Order List - Background Image to include list-style decimal

Tags: css, listitem

I'm working on an ordered list. With a background image on it. What I'd like to do is have the number "1", "2" etc. Sitting on top of the background image. With a suitable padding between the image and the list items.

An example of my work is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/)

Thanks on this one.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write `list-style: decimal inside;` in your css & adjust the your padding. Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/2/

Comment: Small caveat about using 'inside' for list-styles: multi-line items will wrap around your number.  example: http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/8/

Answer (score 1):

This that I wrote might be of use to you http://csswizardry.com/2010/11/mark-up-a-semantic-accessible-progressively-enhanced-mobile-optimised-progress-bar-bonus-style-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list/#section-numbers

H

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `list-style-position: inside;` on the css element `ul.what_list`

shown here -> http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/1/

To be able to change the color of the bullet.  You can't really just do the bullet.  Is what you can do is style the color of the `li` to white.  Then create a `span` with a class of lets say `color` and color that element black.  see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/4/

Comment: Great stuff. What about making the number white, But the content black? Sorry this is a new question

Comment: @StuBlackett check out my addition of your other question

Comment: Hi @Henesnarfel.. Any idea how to get this to work in the dreaded IE7?

Comment: Hi, The decimal point is sitting outside of the list. I've used a conditional stylesheet and turned the list style to none

Comment: @StuBlackett ok.  I can't replicate that issue your having. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little fiddle, using some CSS counter and :before magic: http://jsfiddle.net/KnMhS/7/

```
ol.what_list {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset:item;
}

ol.what_list li {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left:30px;
    min-height: 35px;
    counter-increment:item
}

ol.what_list li:before {
    content: counter(item);
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://i44.tinypic.com/9ihj4m.png) no-repeat  center center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 31px;
    margin-left: -30px;

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 31px;  
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that this isn't supported in all version of IE:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoelements
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#generated